# real-time voice (calling) using WiFi P2P manager on android

Tags: android, wifip2p

I have searched for way to make real-time voice (calls) between two peers but only found how to record voices and send them or sending photos and text. but what I want is for the two peers to be able to call each other. So is it possible that using WiFi P2P manager on android would allow me to create a real-time conversation between the two peers? Does android have that feature?

Comment: Android has [SIP support](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/sip/SipManager.html), although it's not limited to using WiFi.

Comment: @Michael But does the SIP support WifiP2P manager? what I understood from the developer guide is that the SIP is for internet calls

Comment: They are two different things.

Comment: @Michael Sorry, I was't clear. In my project I will use the WifiP2P manager to make calls. does the SIP work with the WifiP2P manager?

Answer (score 1):

Wifi p2p is now called as Wifi Direct you can connect with WifiDirect to transfer files between two or more devices you can find the WifiDirect demo project on android developer site

And if you want to work with SIP you must have a valid sip account some site allows free sip account one of them is can be [Found here](http://www.getonsip.com) after having a valid sip account you can start calling over wifi and you can download one more open source project sipdroid from [Here](https://code.google.com/p/sipdroid/)

Comment: without any sip account i am not able to create voice call application till date if you were succeeds then let me know thanks

Comment: and.... if that's the case, wouldn't it still be possible for using SIP without the server for handling the protocol ? can Adhoc without internet usage use SIP? But what about the Profile @NeerajSharma

Answer (score 0):

Am sure @Ibrahim wants to be able to connect the two android users without a dependency on internet. Using the internet is the 'old' style. Meanwhile do check this library :

https://github.com/fyhertz/libstreaming

There is so much resources here that we are learning from in building connectivity for users here in Africa at large without the need for internet.